# Procedure call through different packages in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Let's say I have two packages : `package_1` and `package_2` and an entity : `my_entity`.

The entity uses the first package

```
-- This is my_entity
USE WORK.package_1.ALL;
```

The package_1 uses the second package;

```
-- This is package_1
USE WORK.package_2.ALL;
```

The package_2 implements a procedure called ... `my_procedure` (y)

```
-- This is package_2
PROCEDURE my_procedure IS ...
```

Now, is there a way to call `my_procedure` from `my_entity`? The current version isn't compiling in Modelsim.

Comment: Other than creating the same named procedure in package_1 that calls package_2.my_procedure, no, or so I don't think so.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 12.4 Use clauses. The use clause in package_1 has a scope that starts immediately after the use clause and extends to the end of declarative region (package_1).  A declaration made directly visible by that use clause is only directly visible within the use clause's scope. You either need a use clause in the entity (or it's architecture, a process statement,...) making my_procedure directly visible or a selected name if the resource library package_2 is located in has been made visible with a library clause. Also see 12.3 Visibility.

Comment: If you don't want to `use work.package2,all` in your entity, put a wrapper procedure in Package1 that calls the Package2 one.

Comment: @Brian Drummond, I thought about this aswell , but this is definitely a waste of time (even though I have to admit that it works fine).

Comment: If it makes the design intent and structure clearer, a minute spent typing boilerplate usually isn't a waste of time (compared to, say, spending an hour figuring out what's going on, or a day debugging, six months later). But you are correct that it depends on the size and scope of the project, and only you know that. Which is why I suggest it as an alternative, not The Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity also requires a reference to:

```
USE WORK.package_2.ALL;
```

In VHDL, a package reference is to a compiled image that is in the library and only gets what is in the corresponding declarative part of the package.   IE: unlike C, it does not get anything from the packages that are referenced by a package.

This is good as it helps isolate declarations - only include what you need and that is all that you get.

Comment: If you only need one thing from `package_2` you can make that explicit with `USE work.package_2.my_procedure;` which makes the dependency explicit and doesn't unnecessarily pollute the namespace.